# How to "render" HTML without WebBrowser control

Tags: c#, javascript, .net, httpwebrequest, webbrowser-control

First at all - I don't know if "render" is the right word. I like to get information from an website. At the moment therefore I use the WebBbrowser control. 
Now I like to use HttpWebRequests because I think, that's much faster and threading could be used more easily. But I can't use them, because the HTML-output string I receive from HttpWebRequest has got a lot of JavaScript inside from which the information, that I need, will be created.
The web browser "renders" the JavaScript to readable HTML. How to do this step "by hand", so that I can use HttpWebRequests?

I hope you understand, what I want.

Comment: You may prefer WebClient over HttpWebRequest. Anyway it sounds like you are trying to scrape pages that are not intended to be used in that way and would violate the terms of use. Did you check if an (WebService) API exists which would allow you to retrieve the information?

Comment: Please revise your question, it's very unclear.

Comment: @user845279 The question itself is pretty clear but has already been answered elsewhere for sure. I leave it to someone else to find the matching duplicate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem with a project called [Awesomium](http://awesomium.com/). In this [thread](http://support.awesomium.com/discussions/questions/499-html-scrapping-with-javascripts) you will find all you need to get html with executed javascript. The "special part" is this one:

```
var sourceVal = webView.ExecuteJavascriptWithResult( "document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].outerHTML;" );

if ( sourceVal != null )
{
    using ( sourceVal )
    {
        html = sourceVal.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: You could also do this using HTTPWebrequest and httpwebresponse objects.

Comment: Could you explain me, how to execute the Javascript inside the html I got from HTTPWebRequest/HTTPWebResponse?

Answer (score 0):

so if you need the javascript rendering engine i suggest you have a look at [selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/) project.