# Can i read iframe through WebClient (i want the outer html)?

Tags: c#, browser, html-parsing, webclient

Well my program is reading a web target that somewhere in the body there is the iframe that i want to read.

**My html source**

```
<html>
...
<iframe src="http://www.mysite.com" ></iframe>
...
</html>
```

in my program i have a method that is returning the source as a string

```
public static string get_url_source(string url)
{
   using (WebClient client = new WebClient())
   {
       return client.DownloadString(url);
   }
}
```

My problem is that i want to get the source of the iframe when it's reading the source, as it would do in normal browsing.

Can i do this only by using [**WebBrowser Class**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx) or there is a way to do it within WebClient or even another class?

**The real question:**
How can i get the outer html given a url? Any appoach is welcomed.

Comment: guess you can access url via java script ..

Comment: Be aware that you might encounter the security issue of cross-site scripting if you are access a page from another domain.

Comment: Yes the iframe is from another domain but why is this a problem?

Comment: @Incognito: see it on wiki [[Cross-site scripting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting)]

Comment: Actually my page involve scripts and after some research i found out that the closest solution so far is this > webBrowser1.Document.ActiveElement.OuterHtml.ToString();
So i need the outer html of the page.
Another similar question is here -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10562051/how-to-render-html-without-webbrowser-control

Comment: @I4V: I didnt understand what you said just know, i asked for any approach to my solution.

Comment: @Incognito: Seems that you want to embed a `WebBrowser` in an `.aspx` page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i found the answer after some search and this is what i wanted

```
webBrowser1.Url = new Uri("http://www.mysite.com/");
while (webBrowser1.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete) Application.DoEvents();
string InnerSource = webBrowser1.Document.Body.InnerHtml; 
                            //You can use here OuterHtml too.
```

Answer (score 3):

After getting the source of the site, you can use [HtmlAgilityPack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) to get the url of the iframe

```
HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);

var src = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//iframe")
            .Attributes["src"].Value;
```

then make a second call to `get_url_source`

Comment: That would cause the iframe to change its data.

Comment: @Incognito, `change its data`? What does it mean? how?

Comment: because its time the iframe loads new data are generated, so i want the data that are generated the 1st time that i load the page. its like having a script that its generating random numbers in the iframe.

Comment: @Incognito `That would cause the iframe to change its data`, i think the correct phrase would be "That would cause the iframe **not** to change its data"

Comment: i mean with the second call on the src of the iframe as you said in your answer, i've tried it out.Each time the src of the iframe is accessed it change its data. So if i used your method to find out the src of the iframe and called the get_url_source, that would call the iframe again and as result that would generate new data that arent usable. Thats why i wanted to get the source/data of the iframe the 1st time that i called my page.

Answer (score 2):

Parse your source using [HTML Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/) and then:

```
List<String> iframeSource = new List<String>();

HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.Load(url);

foreach (HtmlNode node in doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//iframe"))
    iframeSource.Add(get_url_source(mainiFrame.Attributes["src"]));
```

If you are targeting a single iframe, try to identify it using ID attribute or something else so you can only retrieve one source:

```
String iframeSource;

HtmlDocument doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.Load(url);

foreach (HtmlNode node in doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//iframe"))
{
    // Just an example for check, but you could use different approaches...
    if (node.Attributes["id"].Value == 'targetframe')
        iframeSource = get_url_source(node.Attributes["src"].Value);
}
```

Comment: Yes im targeting a single iframe, ill try your example and will reply back.